# Memory management by OS

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

I am trying to understand memory management by the OS .
What I understand till now is that in a 32 bit system ,each process is allocated a space of 4gb [2gb user + 2gb kernel] ,in the virtual address space.
What confuses me is that is this 4gb space unique for every process . if I have say 3 processes p1 ,p2 ,p3 running would I need 12 gb of space on the hard disk ?

Also if say I have 2gb ram on a 32 bit system ,how will it manage to handle a process which needs 4gb ?[through the paging file ] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [2gb user + 2gb kernel]

That is a constraint by the OS. On an x86 32-bit system without PAE enabled, the virtual address space is 4 GiB (note that [GB usually denotes 1000 MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) while GiB stands for 1024 MiB).

> What confuses me is that is this 4gb space unique for every process .

Yes, every process has its own 4 GiB virtual address space.

> if I have say 3 processes p1 ,p2 ,p3 running would I need 12 gb of
>   space on the hard disk ?

No. With three processes, they can occupy a maximum of 12 GiB of storage. Whether that's primary or secondary storage is left to the kernel (primary is preferred, of course). So, you'd need your primary memory size + some secondary storage space to be at least 12 GiB to contain all three processes if all those processes really occupied the full range of 4 GiB, which is pretty unlikely to happen.

> Also if say I have 2gb ram on a 32 bit system ,how will it manage to
>   handle a process which needs 4gb ?[through the paging file ] ?

Yes, in a way. You mean the right thing, but the "paging file" is just an implementation detail. It is used by Windows, but Linux, for example, uses  a seperate swap partition instead. So, to be technically correct, "secondary storage (a HDD, for example) is needed to store the remaining 2 GiB of the process" would be right.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,that clears up a lot things . With regard to the third answer ,if a process does not need 4 gb of space ,is the extra space free to be used by other processes ?

Comment: Say in an hypothetical scenario ,we have a HDD with 12 gb space and a 4 gb ram and we have 12 process running which take 1 gb space each [user data + kernel ,the rest of 3 gb is free]  .Would there be enough memory for them to run ?

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya Yes. Every process always has 4 GiB virtual memory. But whether those 4 GiB are really mapped to physical memory like HDD or RAM is decided by the kernel. So, yes, physical memory to which no page has been mapped to is free for use by other processes.

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya Yes, there would be (not considering the memory used by other parts of the computer like the kernel itsself, memory-mapped I/O devices, etc.). `12 GiB + 4 GiB = 16 GiB`, so this is more than enough for twelve processes à 1 GiB.